# Mule: Reading a large file in chunks using file connector if file size is large

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

Is there a way to consume a file using file connector in mule in small chunks if file size is quite large.

Comment: You can configure the File connector to read the files in a streamed way, go to File properties, connector configuration, and check the "Enable Streaming" box. This will allow you to take the content of the file as you needed. However, depending of the rest of the flow, the file will be processed in chunks or as a whole. What kind of process are you implementing? Do you hay some basic flow? HTH, Marcos.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a transformer that returns an iterable (such as http://www.geekality.net/2011/05/23/java-inputstream-line-iterator if you are interested in each individual line).

Then use a `<foreach batchSize="XXX">...</foreach>` to handle the lines in batch sizes of your choice.